# How to use an enum and switch() with UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My UITableView has two sections, so I created an enum for them:

```
private enum TableSections {
    HorizontalSection,
    VerticalSection
}
```

How do I switch with the "section" var passed in numberOfRowsInSection delegate method?  It seems that I need to cast "section" to my enum type?  Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

The error is **"Enum case "HorizontalSection" not found in type 'int'.**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {

    case .HorizontalSection:
        return firstArray.count

    case .VerticalSection:
        return secondArray.count

    default 
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use raw values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to give your enum a type (Int in this case):

```
private enum TableSection: Int {
    horizontalSection,
    verticalSection
}
```

This makes it so that 'horizontalSection' will be assigned the value 0 and 'verticalSection' will be assigned the value 1.

Now in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method you need to use `.rawValue` on the enum properties in order to access their integer values:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {

    case TableSection.horizontalSection.rawValue:
        return firstArray.count

    case TableSection.verticalSection.rawValue:
        return secondArray.count

    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though @tktsubota pointed me in the right direction, you replied with a complete answer.  I'll mark this one as the Answer. Thank you.

Comment: One remark regarding naming conventions: "Give enumeration types singular rather than plural names, so that they read as self-evident", so preferably use TableSection iso TableSections as name for the enum (cfr [Swift Programming Language guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html))

Comment: @Herre thanks for catching that, I will edit to show that change

Answer (score 6):

Jeff Lewis did it right, to elaborate on that and give the code litlle bit of more readiness -> my way of handling these things is to:

1. Instantiate enum with the raw value -> section index

`guard let sectionType = TableSections(rawValue: section) else {
        return 0
    }`

2. Use switch with section type

`switch sectionType {
        case .horizontalSection:
            return firstArray.count
        case .verticalSection:
            return secondArray.count
    }`

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured it out, thanks @tktsubota for pointing me in the right direction.  I'm pretty new to Swift.  I looked into .rawValue and made some changes:

```
private enum TableSections: Int {
    case HorizontalSection = 0
    case VerticalSection = 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {

    case TableSections.HorizontalSection.rawValue:
        return firstArray.count

    case TableSections.VerticalSection.rawValue:
        return secondArray.count

    default 
        return 0
    }
}
```